# Possible to get Canadian SIM card for data only for a few days?

Tags: canada, cellphones

I'm gonna be in Montreal for a few days but my carrier doesn't provide any service. Is there any Canadian carrier who sells a sim card just for data for a few days? I'm used to the European easiness of buying sim cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two options, indicating it's at least possible for a moderate price:

- [iroam](https://personal.iroam.com/canada-sim.aspx): $15 for a data-only SIM
- [Similicious](https://www.similicious.com/pages/unlimited-in-zone): $40 for unlimited data for a single month (2GB high-speed data, then unlimited data at slower speeds thereafter). This one is not data-only, but I'm sure you could just ignore the text/call options

Answer (score 1):

I can't claim that it's factual and current, but it's certainly thorough. This wiki has a lot of information on prepaid sim cards in Canada.

http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Canada